# Weakly convergent sequence

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, hilbert-spaces

> Consider a sequence $(x_n)_n$ in Hilbert space $H$ such that $\langle x_m,x_n\rangle=\delta_{mn}$ where $\delta_{mn}$ equals one if $m = n$ and $C$ otherwise. Prove that $(x_n)_n$ is a weakly convergent sequence.

Comment: One could use [Bessel's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_inequality).

Comment: Bessel's inequality could be applied to an orthonormal sequence only.

Comment: Oops, I misread that "$C$"...

Comment: If the problem is correct, we necessarily  have $C=0$, otherwise we have $\langle x_m,x_1\rangle =C$ for $m\geqslant 2$.

Comment: Could you explain this in detail?

Comment: I see that your consequences $\langle x_m,x_1\rangle =C$ for $m\geq 2$ is the assumption of problem.

Answer (score 2):

Let $F:=\overline{\operatorname{Span}\{x_n,n\geqslant 1\}}$: it's a closed subspace of $H$, so we have $H=F\oplus F^\perp$.

We know, as $\{x_n\}$ is bounded, that it has a weakly converging subsequence. What we have to prove is that the limit doesn't depend on the choice of the subsequence.

Let $u_0$ a weak limit of $\{x_{k'}\}$. We can write $u_0=u'_0+u''_0$, where $u'_0\in F$ and $u''_0\in F^\perp$.

Testing the definition of weak convergence $\langle x_{k'},v\rangle\to \langle u,v\rangle$ with $v=u''$, we get that $u''=0$, and for each $j$, $\langle u',x_j\rangle=C$.

This determines $u'$, because if $u_1$ and $u_2$ are weak limits of a subsequence of $\{x_n\}$, using the preceding argument we get that $\langle u_1'-u_2',x_j\rangle=C-C=0$ for all $j$, so $\langle u'_1-u'_2,w\rangle=0$ for all $w$ in the linear span of the $x_k$, and by density for all 
$w\in F$, and $u''_1-u''_2=0$.

Comment: I tried as your sketch but I have no result. Could you please give me some hints?

Comment: If $C=0$ then we could use Bessel's inequality. But how can you prove that $C=0$? And I don't understand your last question. Would you please post your proof?

Comment: You have written $\langle x_m,x_1\rangle =C$ for $m\geq 2$ recently but I think this is the assumptions of the problem because we have $\langle x_m,x_n\rangle =C$ when $m\neq n$. Please let me know if I misconstrued your idea.

Comment: I understand your point: the convergence is not necessarily to $0$. I will think more about the problem (at least, the beginning show that we  can restrict ourselves to the closure of the span of the $x_j$).

Comment: @DonDon I've rewritten the argument, now I hope it's correct.

Comment: $u'_0, u''_0$ and $u', u''$ in your argument are the same, aren't they? What is the meaning of  "the limit doesn't depend on the choice of the subsequence"? It is obvious that the limit is unique.

Comment: We _show_ that they are the same. If I take the sequence $(v_0,e_1,v_0,e_2,v_0,e_3,\dots,v_0,e_n,\dots)$ where $v_0\neq 0$, if I take the subsequence $y_{2k}$ I get $v_0$ as a limit, but if I take $y_{2k+1}$ I get $0$. The limit is unique once the subsequence is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

We have $y_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}x_i$ converges to $y$ in $H$. Then $e_i=x_i-y$, $1\leq i\leq n$ is an orthonormal system. Hence, $(e_i)$, $1\leq i\leq n$ are linearly independent.

Let $F_n=\operatorname{Span}\{x_1,\ldots ,x_n\}$, it is a closed subspace of $H$. For all $x$ in $H$, $x=u_n+v_n$, $u_n\in F_n$, $v_n\in F_n^\perp$. Then $u_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\lambda_ke_k$ and $\langle x,e_k\rangle=\lambda_k$. So $u_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\langle x,e_k\rangle e_k$.

By Pythagorean Theorem, $||x||=||\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\langle x,e_k\rangle e_k+v_n||=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}|\langle x,e_k\rangle|^2+||v_n||^2$. Therefore, $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}|\langle x,e_k\rangle|^2\leq||x||$. In other words, the series $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}|\langle x,e_k\rangle|^2$ converges. So $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\langle x,e_k\rangle=0$. We can derive that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\langle x,x_k\rangle=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\langle x,y\rangle$.
Q.E.D